# Are question about NFT markets on topic or third party?

Tags: discussion

Questions about some third parties like Etherscan, Infura, Moralis, etc. are allowed because they are used as building block for new projects and are used a lot by the community.

Opensea also provides an api for NFTs. I'd say we can accept questions about Opensea api because we already allow question for others providers.

But questions about the Opensea as a market, like pricing, should be directed to Opensea customer support.

What's your opinion? Should we allow all questions related to NFT markets, or restrict them to programming questions, or something else.

Answer (score 3):

We don't get much engagement in Meta and don't want to be the only voice, but I agree with you :)